# How to get number of line of a specific word in it in multiline textbox in vb .net

Tags: vb.net

I have a multiline text box and I want to get line number that specific word in it.

I tried this:

```
For Each line As String In TextBox1.Lines
    If line = "50" Then
        Label2.Text = 'Number Of line
    End If
Next
```

But I don't know how to get line number that "50" in it and show it in label2.
how can i do that?

Comment: Doesn't creating a counter and incrementing it as you loop through the lines work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a counter:

```
Dim iLineCount As Integer = 0

For Each line As String In TextBox1.Lines
    iLineCount += 1
    If line = "50" Then
        Label2.Text = iLineCount.ToString()
    End If
Next
```

Comment: dear Slugsie  this code is great. This is exactly what I was looking for. You are the best, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `For`-loop instead of a `For Each`:

```
Dim lines = TextBox1.Lines
For i As Int32 = 0 To lines.Length - 1
    If lines(i) = "50" Then Label2.Text = (i + 1).ToString()
Next
```

I'm storing the `TextBox.Lines` `String()` in a variable because there's [some overhead](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/TextBoxBase.cs,37cabfde1449b18f,references) if you use this property often.

Comment: dear Tim Schmelter this code works like a charm.  You are the best, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Or try this:

```
Dim lines = TextBox1.Lines
Label2.Text = Array.IndexOf(lines, "50").ToString()
```

That will show the (zero based) index of first line to contain "50". Or -1 if no matching lines found.